# Implementation of eSTREAM ciphers available?

Tags: encryption, openssl

Is there a usable implementation of the [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) stream cyphers available for Linux?

I was thinking to use that for encrypting data stored on tape drives, using it with `tar`.

Now, there are some basic implementations in the eSTREAM suite, but they're designed for benchmarking purposes, and are not very usable for every-day use.

I rely on stream cipher [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) right now (`openssl rc4`), but as with DES and AES, I'd like to switch to something more secure, and more modern.

In case there are "better" ways of using encryption on tape drives, please let me know. Block ciphers are obviously not really handy here, since those require random access.

Comment: Quite a few stream ciphers are based on block ciphers, your last sentence doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Mat: Those aren't stream ciphers per se. Those are block ciphers, that work on small blocks and turn them into a functional stream cipher (ECB, CBC, CFB, OFB, etc). I could use a modified block cipher, but when using tape drives, those small blocks might still be too large and cause the tape to stop and change direction a lot.

Comment: That's just not correct. The fact that the block cipher operates on small blocks doesn't have anything to do with how you stream the data to or from the tape. As long as the algo+mode of operation can keep up with the tape drive, you can use a block-cipher based stream cipher just as well as you can use a "native" stream cipher.

Comment: There is a reason to use designed stream ciphers. RC4 has been used for a reason for so long.

Comment: I'm not saying the contrary. Just that your argument that block ciphers can't be used with tape devices is wrong.

Comment: @Mat: You could use a normal FS like ext2 on tape drives, but it just doesn't make sense, since for those kind of applications you need random access. The same way you can use block ciphers on linear media. The point is, that it doesn't perform well. When using a block cipher in in a streaming mode, you can't really say you use block ciphers anymore. You could use stream ciphers based on block ciphers, but bit based stream ciphers like RC4 just perform a lot better in linear applications.

Comment: Look at for example, the LTO format. The official encryption method they standardized on is AES in GCM mode. Do you really think that if block-based ciphers were somehow inappropriate for tape use, they'd have used one? Tape drives work with large, to very large buffers. Whether your cipher is block-based or "pure" stream is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mat: LTO Ultrium is a modern tape drive with things like ROT, and large parallel throughput. Older Drives don't have that kind of capabilities. The latest version of LTO even has it's own file system (LTFS). The drives I'm using aren't that modern.

Comment: Look, simply put, the type of encryption you use is unrelated to the I/O pattern you want to generate for your drive. Especially if you're talking about old drives, the encryption is going to happen on your CPU (or GPU, or a dedicated unit, but certainly not by the drive or cartridge) _before you send it to the drive_. You'll do the I/O to the drive exactly the same way if you're encrypting with a new stream cipher, and old block cipher (ECB or not), ROT13, or nothing at all.